# Searching + Replacing a raw string with double backslashes using regex outputs only a single backslash

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am hoping to get some insight into this issue I am having. I couldn't really find any other questions like this doing the same thing. I am using python 3.7.

I am pulling in contents of strings using regex which then will replace other parts of a JavaScript file I am reading in. I am familiar with raw strings when reading data in, but when I go to replace certain parts containing the double backslash only one is printed. I know it is escaping the string due to the backslash on the \", but I am at a loss with this. Adding a third "\" to it making it "\\\" will solve the issue, but I cannot do that due to the type of data I am working with.

For example, I want to replace all instances that the string "Ch" is found in a file I am reading in with "\\" using regex. This new data is then outputted to a new file.

How do I go about replacing certain content with the string '"\\"' ensuring that nothing is escaped and only "\\" is outputted?

**Simplified sample code for testing:**

```
string = R'"\\"'  
Converted_Text = re.sub("Ch", ' ' + string, Converted_Text)  
with open('output.js','w') as w:
    w.write(Converted_Text.strip().replace('\n',''))
```

**Sample file being read in:**

```
var test = Ex("Temp") + Ch + wn;

var num1= 1;
var num2 =2;
var sum = num1+num2;
var blah, meh;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace `CH` with `\\CH` and again replace `CH` with `\\`.